# Symbols between figures

Tags: beamer, floats, algorithms, shapes

I would like to add symbols between Figures

Figure 1  + Figure 2 ---> Figure 3

Please redirect on how it can be achieved.

Comment: if i understand this correctly, you would like to have a math display that contains "figures" (but not the floating kind, just simple graphics) instead of ordinary math variables.  this should work: `\[ \mbox{\includegraphics{fig1}} + \mbox{\includegraphics{fig2}} \to \mbox{\includegraphics{fig3}} \]`.  if you really want *floating* figures, this is an impossible request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak the following two solutions to suit your needs.

---

**Normal Text Rendering**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\renewcommand{\subfigurename}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{\rule{0.2\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
  \qquad\raisebox{2.0mm}{\noindent\Huge+}\qquad
  \subfloat[]{\rule{0.1\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
  \qquad\raisebox{2.0mm}{{\Huge$\Rightarrow$}}\qquad
  \subfloat[]{\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**Rendered as an Equation**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}
\renewcommand{\subfigurename}{Figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \Huge
  \begin{equation*}
    \subfloat[]{\rule{0.2\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
    +
    \subfloat[]{\rule{0.1\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
    \Rightarrow
    \subfloat[]{\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10.0mm}}
  \end{equation*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I see a major drawback of your solution: If you add a regular figure you will get a second "Figure 1" since your "Figure 1" isn't figure no. 1 but figure no. 0.1 (labeled "Figure 1") instead. Furthermore your solution does not work with a "List of Figures". So I would propose either using `minipage`s, `\parbox`, or `\captionbox` instead, e.g. `\captionbox{}{\rule{0.2\textwidth}{10.0mm}}`.